# Installation of required Dlls when deploying C# application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, dll, deployment

I have a main project A, with multiple subprojects. Among these subprojects, the project B includes Dlls which are required for the applicatioin to run. So I can select these Dlls and set them to be copied after the generation, which works fine.

The problem is, these Dlls are NOT copied when I deploy my project. How can I put these Dlls in the system32/ folder of the destination computer on deployment?

Working on Windows XP with Visual Studio 2008 SP1.
The application will only be installed on XPs.
Simplest way preferred.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you need the DLLs in system32? Having the assemblies local to your application should be all that is required, or if you want to be a bad guy/girl, use the GAC.

Comment: Sure, as long as it works, I'm fine with it...